# Blank page on running AngularJS Application in iFrame in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to run an AngularJS Application in an iFrame in IE8. I get a blank page.
 **Observed Behavior:**
1. Works fine in normal browser window of IE8.
2. Works fine in iFrame of Chrome and FireFox.
3. Works fine if I right click and refresh the iFrame.
4. HTML is fully loaded (Checked in view source). The AngularJS controller is not triggered. None of the alerts and console.logs are displayed.
5. No JS errors are thrown

How do I enable trigger of AngularJS controller, can I manually trigger it on window.onload ?
Any insights and suggestions would help. 
  Unfortunately I have to run the application inside an iframe in IE8 ? Upgrading the browser or choosing different browser is not an option.
  Thanks!
SKR

Comment: What Angular version you're using? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: I'm using AngularJS v1.2.14

Comment: I recently had the same issue with a html page in an iframe in ext.net... the only way I was able to get around it was make new window, if ie8. I hope someone can find an issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally arrived at a solution. 
As I had mentioned in the issue description, the page works fine on refresh.
So the solution is to refresh the page on load.
I used the One time page refresh solution mentioned for the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985507/one-time-page-refresh-after-first-page-load), in particular solution given by [Cokegod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458152/cokegod).
There is no perceptible difference in loading time. The best part is it works in IE8!

Comment: Also works for ifame in IE11 with main document page set to IE8 Enterprise Mode