# Refresh page once using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When I redirect to a page, I want it to refresh automatically only once per load. I want to accomplish this using angularjs. Can someone please help.

Comment: It's better if you use "ui-router", and then you will have "states" which you can "reload()" them. [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/)

Comment: `window.location.reload();` use this where necessary,that will reload your page

Comment: Thanks Hema,  but this refreshes the page multiple times whereas if you have read my question I have asked to refresh just once..

Comment: I was able to find my solution at this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985507/one-time-page-refresh-after-first-page-load   Javascript worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please, never look for refreshing the page while using angular Js. But if you still want to do this, then you can do this by the native JavaScript function. 
Write this code inside the redirected to controller .

```
Windows.reload();
```

Thanks..

Comment: It shows me Windows not defined..could u pls check whether what you wrote is correct?