# Ajax / Javascript - Refresh one time only

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

How can i refresh this page one time only not repeating

```
    function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
  setTimeout("location.reload(false);",timeoutPeriod);
}

window.onload = timedRefresh(3000);

document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='block';
```

Comment: you can use location.reload(); to refresh the page on Ajax success.

Comment: Is the above code on `page1.php`?

Comment: @JackBashford no that is `currentpage.php`

Comment: @onkar.v no, that is not what i meant, please read my problem above again sir, i want to refresh specific pages not the same page

Comment: `window.location.href = "page1.php";`

Comment: you cant reload another page with javascript. you can only redirect or reload current page

Comment: @Zeljka okay thank you for that sir, ive changed my question please see, my question is how can I refresh the page one time only and NOT repeating?

Comment: i will post full answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985507/one-time-page-refresh-after-first-page-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you reload the exact same page so with no way to persist the fact that you already ran that code it will just run it again. 
The old-fashioned way of doing this was using cookies:

```
function timedRefreshIfNoCookie(timeoutPeriod, cookieName) {
    var cookies = document.cookie;
    if (cookies.indexOf(' '+cookieName+'=1;') < 0) {
        document.cookie = cookieName+'=1';
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload();
        }, timeoutPeriod);
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    timedRefreshIfNoCookie(3000, 'refreshed');
}    
document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='block';
```

You can probably use something a bit better like local storage or a cookie library to work with cookies more easily.

Comment: hey sir thanks it worked ! but one last problem is why the page is refreshin every like 3 seconds? can we just remove that refresh because it refresh everytime my pc lags :(

Comment: i mean let's just hide that refresh but tho even if it is hide the page will still refresh

Comment: The page should just refresh once after 3 seconds and then not refresh again. Is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

```
int refresh=0;  

function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
  setTimeout("location.reload(false);",timeoutPeriod);
  refresh=1;
}

if(refresh==0){
window.onload = timedRefresh(3000);
}


document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='block';
```

you can add a flag boolean or integer to check if page is loaded or not

Answer (score 0):

you can refresh the page by using PHP

```
header('Refresh: 0; url=page1.php');
```

To refresh the current page, you can use -

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

Comment: you cant use header in javascript, its php function

Answer (score 0):

Although Zeljka's linked answer is future proof, if you already use hashes for navigation it might better to use [performance.navigation.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type).

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(performance.navigation.type != 1) {
       timedRefresh(3000);
    }
}

function timedRefresh(time) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload()
    }, time);
}
```

Note that the NavigationType is depreciated, but looks like the new spec will have an equivalent when it arrives.